# How come i can't center this html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center this menu. How come i can't center it with the two types of ways i tried to center it? I tried to center it with html and css as shown with comments. I'm just wondering why, I could probably figure it out but it would take me a long time. I know I can fix it with position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%; But even that, how do i use that in a good way? how do i use absolute positioning correctly and in a good way? Also what is relative position? What is that used for and how does that compare to absolute? Plz and thank you.

Here's my CSS:

```
ul {
    text-align: center; /* How come this doesn't center it? */
    padding: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a.menuItem:link,
a.menuItem:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #800000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.menuItem:hover,
a.menuItem:active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<center> <!-- And how come this doesn't center it? -->
    <ul background="/victoria/cutiepie2.jpg">
        <li><a href="/scripts/call.php" class="menuItem">Call</a></li>
        <li><a href="/scripts/text.html" class="menuItem">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu/home.html" class="menuItem">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu/news.html" class="menuItem">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu/media.html" class="menuItem">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu/downloads.html" class="menuItem">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu/forum.html" class="menuItem">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</center>
```

Comment: The `<Center>` element has been deprecated under HTML5 and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 2):

A `UL` element is a block level element, it therefore cannot be influenced by `text-align: center` which only works on inline elements such as `span`, `strong`, `em` etc. It can be applied to a block so that any textual or inline elements inside it are centered but it will not center the block. A block level element will expand to fill all of the horizontal space therefore cannot be centered without first defining it's width.

A better solution would be to place a width on the menu and then set the horizontal margins to auto:

```
ul {
    padding: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also `center` tags are deprecated but in their day, they were also used to center text.

Here is a fiddle showing the centered menu: http://jsfiddle.net/7Hjvc/1/

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. I'm a newbie so it's gonna take me a little while to stop asking questions like that. But um what does margin auto do exactly, even though i probably know? But thank you. That just what i needed and makes complete sense.

Comment: Margin auto basically means that it will distribute the margin evenly to either side of the element you apply it to. If that element is full width the margin either side is 0. If you specify a width it will distribute the remaining side either side.

Comment: Also if you are happy with the answer, please click the tick on my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` from your `LI`, and add display:inline, e.g

```
li {
    display:inline
}
```

And remove `display:block` from your links.

The `text-align:center` on your `UL` was not centering your `LI`s because `LI` are block elements and you were applying a float to them.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you. Yeah I'm not familar with everything exactly. And that's why I'm trying to. Like I said to the other guy. It's gonna take me a while to stop asking questions like that. I should've known it was a block level elment but yeh. Thank you. :) Idk why I keep getting these bad votes. :l You people are tough on voting. And I guess my question was kinda eh.

Comment: I think you got a downvote for the inappropriate class names. The question was fine apart from that, although it's a possible duplicate, but don't stop asking questions, its how we all learn, so don't be dissuaded.